# How to run Ansible with Kerberos in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, ansible, kerberos

My folder structure is like this:

```
ansible
   |── inventory
   |── roles
   └── various ansible stuff
Dockerfile
krb5.conf
```

I have set up Kerberos properly and can run all Ansible playbook on the machine with no problems. But some issues appear when I try to do the same thing after putting Ansible in a container.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install sshpass
RUN apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install ansible
RUN apt-get -y install python-dev libkrb5-dev krb5-user
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python get-pip.py
RUN pip install pywinrm[kerberos]
ADD ./krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
VOLUME /ansible
RUN apt-get -y install curl
```

I build the container first `docker build -t ansible .` then run it with `docker run -it -p 5985:5985 -p 5986:5986 -v $(pwd)/ansible:/ansible ansible`

Hosts that connect directly using SSH or WinRM without going through Kerberos still work, can be connected to, and the playbooks still run. But for hosts going through Kerberos, any command will return `UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "kerberos: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 500", "unreachable": true}`

Example of my inventory file:

```
working_host:
  hosts:
    working:
      ansible_host: working.host
      ansible_connection: winrm
      ansible_port: 5986
      ansible_user: admin
      ansible_password: admin
      ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore

not_working_host:
  hosts:
    not_working:
      ansible_host: not-working.host
      ansible_connection: winrm
      ansible_port: 5985
      ansible_user: user@DOMA.IN
      ansible_password: !vault |
            $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
            RANDOM_ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD
      ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

My krb5.conf is like this

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = DOMA.IN

[realms]
  DOMA.IN = {
    kdc = doma.in
  }

[domain_realm]
  doma.in = DOMA.IN
```

I can ping the host, and curl to `not-working.host:5985` is successful and returns the same thing as when I try outside the container. The container also can ping `doma.in`.

So, the question is: what exactly is going on and why is the container not working for only Windows hosts connecting over Kerberos and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure out how to get it working?